# Update PHP and MySQL server instances

Tags: php, mysql, iis, updating

I am working on a mobile application that communicates with an IIS server to synchronize data among application users. 

   The server is implemented in PHP and MySQL. The final procuct will consist of the server and the application. In other words, every client (company) is going to use a different server and the employees of each company will be the users of the mobile application. As soon as the application is released, bugs are expected to come up. Therefore, each synchronization server will require updates. The db schema and the PHP code will probably need to be altered. Using git to have clients fetch the most recent version of the server is not an option since the clients are not able to handle issues such as merge conflicts. 

   I need to automate the update process as much as possible. Is there any tool or piece of advice that would help me do so?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for the MySQL part to write you own migartions(PHP scripts) which if carefully tested should do the DB migrations correctly. The customers MUST be forbidden to modify the database or you'll never be able to handle migrations correctly.

The second part with PHP sync, I really don't understand what's the problem using git - I think that the right way to go. I don't understand your concerns about the conflicts because the customers wont have to deal with this. When you merge the branches you will have to deal with the conflicts yourself and after you push it to the git server the clients will only have to "pull" the new version.

So to finalize you should create a script that when a new version is available should git pull the version and after that execute the DB migration script(if any).